# Integer to string cast, Delphi typecast

Tags: delphi, casting

While doing maintenance work in Delphi I ran into some code that I don't understand. I wrote a simple console app to help me think this through but I am still confused. If you look at the attached code you will see that I've only put 1 comment in it. That is the location of my question.

I thought that maybe the value being put into X might be the string's address, or maybe the bit values of each (Unicode) char in the string were used to arrive at the value in X however if you run the program multiple times the value of X appears to be random on each iteration.

Any adult supervision would be appreciated, thanks.

```
program OrdinalProject;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;
var
  A : string;
  B : ^string;
  X : integer;
begin
  A := 'ABCD';
  WriteLn(Format('Content of A = %s',[A]));
  WriteLn(Format('Address of A = %p',[@A]));
  WriteLn('');

  B := @A;
  WriteLn(Format('Content of B = %p',[B]));
  WriteLn(Format('Address of B = %p',[@B]));
  WriteLn('');

  X := integer(A); // What is going on here and why doesn't this fail?
  WriteLn(Format('Content of X = %d',[X]));
  WriteLn(Format('Address of X = %p',[@X]));
  Readln;
end.
```

Thank you for the responses! I understand this now.

Comment: It simply casts the address of the string to an integer

Comment: It's the address of the payload. Try "writeln(pchar(x))". Some compiler magic there... I don't know why.

Comment: @Sertac, it's not so magical :) You can store pointer to an integer variable (if it fits), so as you can cast such back to a typed pointer.

Comment: @Victoria - It's not a simple type cast, I repeat, it's the address of the payload. The compiler acts as if you've written `integer(@A[1])`.

Comment: @Sertac, so as if you wrote `PChar(@A[1])`, no? It's just implicit.

Comment: @Victoria - I'm not sure I follow, but probably yes. Pretty much everything about strings involve compiler magic.

Comment: @Sertac, agreed, I would call that a compiler magic :)

Comment: @sertac it's a simple typecast given that a string variable holds the address of the first character of the string.

Comment: @David - Ok. I wonder what was I hoping it to hold...